# Is this email an indication of an unofficial offer?

Tags: job-offer, united-states, email

I received this email from a potential employer yesterday and thought that I was close to an official offer from the company. I replied to the email yesterday and I haven't heard from them yet.

Can anyone please help me decipher this message. Is that an indication that I am close to receiving a job offer from the company? Also, they already spoke to my references. Below is the exact email that I received yesterday.

> I want you to know that you are  being considered for this position and wanted to just go over a few things. We initially discussed a salary of X to start plus you need healthcare insurance as well.  I have not gone over vacation time but I am sure there is one to two weeks.  You are available to start right way?

Comment: `I want you to know that you are being considered for this position` - While that sounds promising, I wouldn't take that as any indication that they're "close" to offering you the position. Additionally, the process of getting hired at most companies usually takes more time than you'd like it to. Understand that hiring you (or anyone else) is just one of the myriad tasks they have on their plate. Patience is a virtue. That's not to say that you shouldn't follow up with them or press them for an answer, but also don't expect them to reply to your communication instantaneously.

Answer (score 3):

It says you're being considered, which suggests they might offer you the job.  It looks like an attempt to get some of the conditions right, which is promising.  However, possible offers fall through more often than not, so don't get your hopes too high or stop looking for work.  Chances are that this is going out to other applicants also.

I find the wording odd, if it's from HR or a hiring manager at the company.  Someone working for the company should have a good idea what the vacation policy is.  If this came from a third-party recruiter it's less promising.

Comment: Thanks, David. It came from a third-party, someone who is helping the Managing Director with the recruiting process. I also have the impression that the same email was going out to other candidates as well.

Answer (score 0):

It says you are considered for the position. All you can be sure of is that they have not rejected you yet.

This may be that you are close to getting an offer. Or it may be that you're on a short list of 10 people. There is no way to tell.

It's not until you have a signed document on the company's letterhead that you have a formal offer. (Yes, I know in many jurisdictions a verbal agreement stands as well -- but it's a lot harder to proof what was said than what was written).